# Python - Pandas - ignore data after blanks

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm working on a program that will read data from an excel file. The excel files have rows of data that I'm interested in, then rows of blanks, then a few rows of data that is irrelevant and I would like to exclude from my data frame.

This is what my data frame looks like:

```
   Ingredient  Pounds Used
0        1705      8800.00
1      ZR100S      2934.00
2      *STOCK       321.00
17    Gravity         1.08
```

How do I go about ignoring the rows at the end? I only want rows 0-2 here.

I've tried a few things, but unfortunately the rows at the end vary in number and how close they are to my desired rows, so I can't just cut off the tail end. I need to be able to work my way down the rows until I find a row that is blank, and then stop.

Comment: I would like to help you, but you need to be more precise . First, do the blank rows  are completely blank ( no value at all ) . If you could provide the complete preview of dataframe it would help a lot.

Comment: as well as your code.

Answer (score 0):

First reset index to make your current index a column. This is because df.index does not accept .shift()
Check the consecutive rows in index are consecutive.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)# reset index
df[(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(-1))-1))|(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(1))+1))].set_index('index')
```

**Step by Step**

```
#step 1
df.reset_index(inplace=True)# reset index

#step 2
(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(-1))-1))#First consecutive check
(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(1))+1))#Second consecutive check

#step 3
#(first)or(second) expressed as (first)|(second) combines them thus

(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(-1))-1))|(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(1))+1))

#step4- get dataframe you go df[(first)or(second)].Thus;
df[(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(-1))-1))|(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(1))+1))]

#step5- return dataframe to original shape by resetting index
df[(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(-1))-1))|(df['index'].eq((df['index'].shift(1))+1))].set_index('index')




       Ingredient  PoundsUsed
index                       
0           1705      8800.0
1         ZR100S      2934.0
2         *STOCK       321.0
```